# Filter of perception

Tags: sensory-perception

I read a book about sensory perception in ASD from Olga Bogdashina(Sensory Perceptual Issues in Autism and Asperger Syndrome, Second Edition).

She reffer to some kind of filter in sensory inputs, but Whats Is exacly that filter ? How it can be dameged in persons with autism?

Comment: Can you quote a section of the book that you want clarified? I'm not sure what you mean by "sense of autistic people can be turn off or become sharp".

Comment: Its just allegory. I dont think that is right to say, they ignore their surroundings because they doing somethink very interesting. You know it just looks like they turn off their senses. And this is the question. Why does IT look like that??

Comment: So _"But what make sharp( turn it of) ?"_ is the equivalent of _"Why does it look like that?"_?